# Trigger registerChange of ControlValueAccessor programmatically?

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular custom form component which is a date selector. Three `select` boxes display year, month and day. When the year or the month is changed, the day options are recalculated to offer the exact number of days in the selected month. The component returns a `Date` object to the parent component's `FormGroup`.

Here is the problem. When the component is initialized, its value is `null`. It stays `null` until the user changes one of the `select` boxes, which invokes `registerOnChange()`, thus setting the control's value. The `Date` object which is returned via `ControlValueAccessor` is calculated by a simple function from the values of the three `select` boxes. Now, how can I invoke `registerOnChange()` programmatically, without the user actually changing anything? The control has the value of `null` unless this happens.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I helped myself. Seems that `registerOnChange()` runs automatically on init. The desired value can be inserted like this:

```
onChange: any = () => { };

registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
    this.onChange(this.calcDate());
}
```